# How to make a dll access managed code, but expose functions to unmanaged binary

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr, managed

So here's my situation: I am working with a binary written in unmanaged c++ that allows the user to specify a .dll to customize functionality; the c++ app will call certain functions in the dll. In this case, the dll will rely on functionality packaged in a .NET .dll from a third party (I have no control over it). My task is to write the dll used by the c++ app. I'm more comfortable working with c++, but can use c# if it makes significantly more sense. How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I've googled the problem with limited success. Note this is one of the very few times I've worked with managed/unmanaged code, so my knowledge is somewhat lacking.

Comment: it absolutely depends on the .NET dll - if it is COM visible you could write an unmanaged (=native) wrapper in C++ . If it is not COM visible it gets much more complicated since then you would probable need to write 2 wrappers: one managed wrapper to expose it via COM and a native wrapper for you managed wrapper...

Comment: Due to my inexperience, I may not be able to tell the difference. I loaded the .NET dll into dependency walker, and did not see any listed exported functions; I assume this would mean it is not COM visible. If so, is there an automated way to generate a COM-visible wrapper for a .NET binary? Or would it have to be written by hand?

Comment: You have few options if you can't change both ends.  You'll need to focus on getting the CLR loaded first so you can execute managed code.  Start that journey by googling CorBindToRuntimeEx, CLRCreateInstance for .NET 4 and up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile your c++ dll with the [`/crl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) option. Its exports would be normally visible to a native c++ application. Additionally it would be able to load a dll with a .NET assembly with the [`Assembly::LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y0) routine.